# Posting input form data

Tags: ruby, forms, post

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://interschool.webs.com/'), 'sgE-670895-3-2' => 'sgE-670895-3-2-10176','sGizmoSubmitButton' => 'Submit')
puts x.body
```

Should post a vote on the website http://interschool.webs.com/ (Parameters should correspond to the last choice on the list as a place holder); however it doesn't work. This is the first time I have every really messed around with sending data so I'm in the dark as to why this isn't working.

This is for a math competition that my school is competing in. We're told to vote and try and reach certain goal. (Most/Least/Closest to Mid/etc) and are told we can use vote bots.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - in what way?  Does your script run without errors but the vote isn't registered?  Or does your script throw an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: There is no error, that I can see. It does return a "null" value but beyond that there's no actual error message. The program doesn't fulfill it purpose and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try Restclient (http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client). That will make liefe easier.

Comment: Well I checked it out and I'm not sure how to install Gems on my comp (win7 x64bit). When I try and download RubyGems I get a blank/corrupted zip file.

Beyond that the help file for Restclient isn't very informative and I'm not sure how I would even begin to apply it to my problem.

Comment: you should have rubygems as a standard library with your ruby interpreter. I'm not sure about Windows but on other systems you do `gem install rest-client` and then you have it.